# Getting notified when event will added to the local Calendar

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I want a notification in my app whenever any event will added to the local calendar. I can get the list of all Calendar Events but we didn't get notification when new event has been added currently. So, please suggest me any solution regarding to the same.

Thanks in advance.

**Code for getting all Event List:**

```
public class Utility {
    public static ArrayList<String> nameOfEvent = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> startDates = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> endDates = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static ArrayList<String> readCalendarEvent(Context context) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(
                        Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                        new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description",
                                "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null,
                        null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // fetching calendars name
        String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];

        // fetching calendars id
        nameOfEvent.clear();
        startDates.clear();
        endDates.clear();
        descriptions.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {

            nameOfEvent.add(cursor.getString(1));
            startDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))));
            endDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4))));
            descriptions.add(cursor.getString(2));
            CNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }
        return nameOfEvent;
    }
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be notified whenever the calendar changes you need to setup a BroadcastReceiver and requery the calendar.

See this question:

[Listen to android calendar changes. (Sync/Delete/Insert etc..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018619/listen-to-android-calendar-changes-sync-delete-insert-etc)